# undefined index error when adding data to php array

Tags: php

I have a php page that is using an associative array:

```
$piececount = array(array());
        $data = '';
                while($calls = sqlsrv_fetch_array($objRs, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $data = '{#'.$calls["USR_ID"].'`'.date('mdY',strtotime($calls["DTE"])).'#}';
                    $piececount[$data]["count"] += $calls["SER_QTY"]; //This tallys up serial piece count per asset per day
```

This works, but for every iteration of the while loop PHP is logging the following errors:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: {#41`01292019#} in C:\inetpub\wwwteam\Schedule\schedule.php on line 341
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: count in C:\inetpub\wwwteam\Schedule\schedule.php on line 341
```

I know this is due to the index not being initialized but for the life of me i cannot figure out how to fix this.
Anyone have any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Initialize it first. `if(!array_key_exists($data, $piececount)) $piececount[$data] = array('count'=>0);`

Comment: @aynber that is it! I tried all sorts of array_key_exists combinations to no avail.